# How to remove post listing page for a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, customization, admin-menu

I want to provide functionality to create a single post into my custom post type.
And for this, when user click on main option (name of post) at left side bar in word-press back-end It's automatically redirect on "Add New Post" or if a post already created then automatically redirect on "Edit Post" (existing post edit).

Right now at back-end the post option look like this -

[image: My Posts]

So, now i don't want sub menu. and preform add/edit post option on main menu click.
Is this possible, if yes then can you please tell me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I get a way to override this problem. by using "add_action" I can able to achieve my goal.

```
  add_action("load-edit.php", 'block_listing_page');
  //-- Block user to access post listing page    
  function block_listing_page() {
        if ($_GET["post_type"] == "your_custom_post_type") {
            $args = array('post_type' => 'your_custom_post_type', 'post_status' => 'publish');
            $galleryPosts = get_posts($args);
            if (!empty($galleryPosts) && count($galleryPosts) > 0) {
                wp_redirect("post.php?post=" . $galleryPosts[0]->ID . "&action=edit");
            } else {
                wp_redirect("post-new.php?post_type=your_custom_post_type");
            }
        }
    }

    add_action("load-post-new.php", 'block_create_multiple_gallery');
    //-- Check if a post is exist open in edit mode when clicking add new post
    function block_create_multiple_gallery() {
        if ($_GET["post_type"] == "your_custom_post_type") {
            $args = array('post_type' => 'your_custom_post_type', 'post_status' => 'publish');
            $galleryPosts = get_posts($args);
            if (!empty($galleryPosts) && count($galleryPosts) > 0) {
                wp_redirect("post.php?post=" . $galleryPosts[0]->ID . "&action=edit");
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

But, **still i want to hide sub menu (i.e "Add New"); Can anyone help me to get this done?**

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the right hooks (which are not always the same as the URLs/slugs), and it doesn't hurt to use a hook that runs later (e.g., admin_init):

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'wpaws_136058_remove_menu_pages' );

function wpaws_136058_remove_menu_pages() {



    /*You can check list of menu item by below code:
    foreach ($GLOBALS['menu'] as $key => $value) {          
        print('<pre');
        print_r($value);
        print('</pre>');
    }
    */

    //Remove item from menu
    remove_menu_page('menu_to_remove');

}
```